# How to read GRIB2 file with PHP

Tags: php, grib, gfs

I would like to display weather forecast data coming from NOAA GFS data subset generated by http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/ filter. As far as I know, the output file is in GRIB2 format. Unfortunately I cannot find any PHP library, which will "give me" forecast for given lat/lon coordinates (I have found some only for Fortran or Python). Does anybody know such a PHP library?

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not....